# Suspend and hibernate both freeze the system with recent update to 5.3.0-42-generic

Tags: suspend, 19.10, freeze, hibernate

I have a Lenovo X1 Gen 7 system. The suspend and hibernate systemd's used to work just fine until I updated the kernel from 5.3.0-40 to 5.3.0-42. Now both of these commands cause the system to go blank and freeze. The only option to recover is to force a reboot.

Here is the system log:

```
Mar 20 18:37:17 user-X1 kernel: [  924.345146] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc:dd:75:1f:cc:f7:35:93:b8:70:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.10 DST=192.168.1.11 LEN=347 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56414 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60000 DPT=57875 LEN=327 
Mar 20 18:37:18 user-X1 kernel: [  925.265951] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc:dd:75:1f:cc:f7:35:93:b8:70:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.10 DST=192.168.1.11 LEN=347 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56432 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60000 DPT=57875 LEN=327 
Mar 20 18:37:19 user-X1 kernel: [  926.388195] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc:dd:75:1f:cc:f7:35:93:b8:70:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.10 DST=192.168.1.11 LEN=347 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56441 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60000 DPT=57875 LEN=327 
Mar 20 18:37:19 user-X1 kernel: [  927.109275] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc:dd:75:1f:cc:f7:35:93:b8:70:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.10 DST=192.168.1.11 LEN=347 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56480 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60000 DPT=57875 LEN=327 
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 NetworkManager[1139]: <info>  [1584747455.5689] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 NetworkManager[1139]: <info>  [1584747455.5691] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 kernel: [  942.784776] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 NetworkManager[1139]: <info>  [1584747455.6589] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 NetworkManager[1139]: <info>  [1584747455.6599] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 whoopsie[2024]: [18:37:35] offline
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 SpiderOakONE.desktop[2777]: No systemtrayicon available
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 gnome-shell[2498]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js 135]: Too many arguments to method Clutter.Actor.destroy: expected 0, got 1
Mar 20 18:37:35 user-X1 gnome-shell[2498]: message repeated 2 times: [ JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js 135]: Too many arguments to method Clutter.Actor.destroy: expected 0, got 1]
Mar 20 18:37:40 user-X1 systemd[1]: Starting TLP suspend/resume...
Mar 20 18:37:40 user-X1 wpa_supplicant[1135]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-50 noise=9999 txrate=585100
Mar 20 18:37:41 user-X1 kernel: [  948.871800] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc:dd:75:1f:40:b0:76:75:2f:70:08:00 SRC=74.126.144.11 DST=192.168.1.11 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=52 ID=5157 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52942 WINDOW=303 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Mar 20 18:37:42 user-X1 systemd[1]: Started TLP suspend/resume.
Mar 20 18:37:42 user-X1 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 20 18:37:42 user-X1 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 20 18:37:42 user-X1 systemd-sleep[7232]: Suspending system...
```

Here is the swap allocation:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.8Gi       8.2Gi       525Mi       4.4Gi        11Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi
```

Anyone sees any issue that can be fixed?

Comment: I updated the question. But does suspend use swap?

Comment: Susoend, no; hibernation, si. I suspect a bug to report at https://launchpad.net

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1861837 fixed in 5.3.0-43

Comment: @K7AAY, I am new to Linux. What made you think this is a bug? Just curious, thought to learn something.